# Rock Paper Scissors game with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have recently got into coding with JavaScript and decided to make a game, to test my knowledge. Nothing happens when I press on the objects supposed to start the game, and when I send information through the console, (most of the time) nothing happens.

```
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor');
const result_in = document.getElementById("result")
let computer;
let computer_pick;
let result;

//Player choice
rock.onclick = play('rock');
paper.onclick = play('paper');
scissor.onclick = play('scissor');

function play(userinput) {    
    computer_pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
    console.log(computer_pick);
    if (computer_pick === 0) { 
        computer = 'rock'
    } else if (computer_pick === 1) {
        computer = 'paper';
    } else if (computer_pick === 2) {
        computer = 'scissor';
    } else { console.log('error') };
    console.log(computer); 
    //
    if (computer == userinput) { //tie
        result = 'tie';
    } else if (computer == 'rock' && userinput == 'paper' || computer == 'paper' && userinput == 'scissor' || computer == 'scissor' && userinput == "rock") {
        console.log(win);
        result = 'win';
    } else if (computer == 'rock' && userinput == 'scissor' || computer == 'paper' && userinput == 'scissor' || computer == 'scissor' && userinput == 'paper') {
        console.log(loss);
        result = 'lost';
    }
//output
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = You ${result}! The computer threw ${computer}.;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Add your HTMl code as well.

Comment: `rock.onclick` -- but where do you define `rock`?

Comment: `console.log(win);` and `console.log(loss);` should throw error as those variables are not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. `rock.onclick` is not correct - `rock.addEventlistener('click', function(e) {})` is correct
2. `console.log(win)` (or loss) is not correct - you try to `console.log()` a variable that doesn't exist - to output a string in `console.log()` you should put it in quotes `console.log('win')`
3. `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = You ${result}! The computer threw ${computer}.;` is not correct - you should use backticks for string interpolation
4. You didn't define `rock` as you did `paper` and `scissor`
5. This is not an coding error, but a simple logic problem: you have three result ALTERNATIVES: **tie**, **win**, **lost**. If it's not a **tie** and user hasn't **win** (won), then user **lost**. You don't need the last `else if`, only `else`
6. The same is true for the **computer_pick** variable - there's no room for error (the random value can only be 0, 1 or 2), so you don't need the `else` for **error**. And if **computer_pick** is not 0 or 1, then it has to be 2 (no need for the `else if`, only for `else`).

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('rock');
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor');
const result_in = document.getElementById("result");
let computer;
let computer_pick;
let result;

//Player choice
rock.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  play('rock')
})
paper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  play('paper')
})
scissor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  play('scissor')
})

function play(userinput) {
  computer_pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log('computer_pick:', computer_pick);
  if (computer_pick === 0) {
    computer = 'rock'
  } else if (computer_pick === 1) {
    computer = 'paper';
  } else {
    computer = 'scissor';
  }
  console.log('computer:', computer);
  //
  if (computer == userinput) { //tie
    result = 'tie';
  } else if (computer == 'rock' && userinput == 'paper' || computer == 'paper' && userinput == 'scissor' || computer == 'scissor' && userinput == "rock") {
    console.log('win');
    result = 'win';
  } else {
    console.log('lost');
    result = 'lost';
  }
  //output
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `You ${result}! The computer threw ${computer}.`;
}
```

```html
<div id="rock">ROCK</div><br />
<div id="paper">PAPER</div><br />
<div id="scissor">SCISSORS</div><br />

<div>RESULT: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

And you could go a bit further by thinking through the logic:

```js
// you can use a query selector with a class
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

// gameRulesObj to define what beats what
const gameRulesObj = {
  "rock": "paper",
  "paper": "scissor",
  "scissor": "rock"
}

btns.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    appendToDOMElement('result', play(this.getAttribute('id'), computerPick(gameRulesObj), gameRulesObj))
  })
})

// this function decides if player wins, loses or ties
function play(userinput, computer, obj) {
  let result;
  if (computer === userinput) {
    result = 'tie';
  } else if (obj[computer] === userinput) {
    result = 'win';
  } else {
    result = 'lost';
  }
  return {
    result,
    computer
  };
}

// this function controls what the computer picks
const computerPick = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(obj).length)]
}

// this function adds the result to the DOM
const appendToDOMElement = (container, {
  result,
  computer
}) => {
  document.getElementById(container).textContent = `You ${result}! The computer threw ${computer}.`
}
```

```html
<div id="rock" class="btn">ROCK</div><br />
<div id="paper" class="btn">PAPER</div><br />
<div id="scissor" class="btn">SCISSORS</div><br />

<div>RESULT: <span id="result"></span></div>
```

The second snippet above gives a bit of a structure to the code:

- every function has one and only one purpose (they can be described with one line of comment); this means that it's easier to change parts of your app
- a lot of variables are eliminated, so you don't have to keep track of them
- one variable added (`gameRulesObj`), so you can define your base rules in one place; the functions now work with any number and set of rules

I know that this structure may be overkill for a simple game like this, but it's good for practicing :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you waiting until the DOM is loaded?

Where are you inject this file to DOM? in `head` tag or `body` tag!

If you inject this code in `head` tag you need to wait until the DOM become loaded

something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Your script
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try `< button onClick=play('rock')>` and so on

and you need " " for the line `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = " "`

Comment: Sorry, but **"** won't work in this case. String interpolation is used, that **requires** backticks; `onclick=""` is not advised - it couples the DOM with your code, and AFAIK it's going to be deprecated soon.